# Django version not found when running docker-compose with python3.9 alpine image

Tags: python, django, docker

Hi I'm trying to build out a basic app django within a python/alpine image.

I am getting en error telling me that there is no matching image for the version of Django that I am looking for.

The Dockerfile in using a `python:3.9-alpine3.14` image and my requirements file is targeting `Django>=3.2.5,<3.3`.

From what i understand these should be compatible, Django >= 3 and Python 3.9.

When I run `docker-compose build` the RUN command gets so far as the `apk add` commands but fails on `pip`. I did try changing this to `pip3` but this had no effect.

Any idea what I am missing here that will fix this issue?

`requirements.txt`

```
Django>=3.2.5,<3.3
uWSGI>=2.0.19.1,<2.1
```

`Dockerfile`

```
FROM python:3.9-alpine3.14
LABEL maintainer="superapp"

ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

COPY requirements.txt /requirements.txt
RUN mkdir /app
COPY ./app /app
COPY ./scripts /scripts
WORKDIR /app

EXPOSE 8000

RUN python -m venv /py && \
    /py/bin/pip install --upgrade pip && \
    apk add --update --no-cache --virtual .build-deps \
    build-base \
    gcc \
    linux-headers && \
    /py/bin/pip install -r /requirements.txt && \
    apk del .build-deps && \
    adduser --disabled-password --no-create-home rsecuser && \
    mkdir -p /vol/web/static && \
    chown -R rsecuser:rsecuser /vol && \
    chmod -R 755 /vol && \
    chmod -R +x /scripts

ENV PATH="/scripts:/py/bin:$PATH"

USER rsecuser

CMD ["run.sh"]
```

`docker-compose.yml`

```
version: "3.9"

services:
  app:
    build:
      context: .
    command: >
      sh -c "python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000"
    ports:
      - 8000:8000
    volumes:
      - ./app:/app
      - ./data/web:/vol/web
    environment: 
      - SECRET_KEY=development_key
      - DEBUG=1
```

Error

```
...
...
...
(20/22) Installing build-base (0.5-r2)
(21/22) Installing linux-headers (5.10.41-r0)
(22/22) Installing .build-deps (20210714.193049)
Executing busybox-1.33.1-r2.trigger
OK: 212 MiB in 58 packages
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement Django<3.3,>=3.2.5 (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for Django<3.3,>=3.2.5
ERROR: Service 'app' failed to build : The command '/bin/sh -c python -m venv /py &&     /py/bin/pip install --upgrade pip &&     apk add --update --no-cache --virtual .build-deps     build-base     gcc     linux-headers &&     /py/bin/pip install -r /requirements.txt &&     apk del .build-deps &&     adduser --disabled-password --no-create-home rsecuser &&     mkdir -p /vol/web/static &&     chown -R rsecuser:rsecuser /vol &&     chmod -R 755 /vol &&     chmod -R +x /scripts' returned a non-zero code: 1(20/22) Installing build-base (0.5-r2)
(21/22) Installing linux-headers (5.10.41-r0)
(22/22) Installing .build-deps (20210714.193049)
Executing busybox-1.33.1-r2.trigger
OK: 212 MiB in 58 packages
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement Django<3.3,>=3.2.5 (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for Django<3.3,>=3.2.5
ERROR: Service 'app' failed to build : The command '/bin/sh -c python -m venv /py &&     /py/bin/pip install --upgrade pip &&     apk add --update --no-cache --virtual .build-deps     build-base     gcc     linux-headers &&     /py/bin/pip install -r /requirements.txt &&     apk del .build-deps &&     adduser --disabled-password --no-create-home rsecuser &&     mkdir -p /vol/web/static &&     chown -R rsecuser:rsecuser /vol &&     chmod -R 755 /vol &&     chmod -R +x /scripts' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

As per comments below, same command run with `/py/bin/pip -vv install -r /requirements.txt` in the Dockerfile.

```
(21/22) Installing linux-headers (5.10.41-r0)
(22/22) Installing .build-deps (20210714.195119)
Executing busybox-1.33.1-r2.trigger
OK: 212 MiB in 58 packages
Using pip 21.1.3 from /py/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pip (python 3.9)
Non-user install because user site-packages disabled
Created temporary directory: /tmp/pip-ephem-wheel-cache-gyetbpa_
Created temporary directory: /tmp/pip-req-tracker-og42yr4p
Initialized build tracking at /tmp/pip-req-tracker-og42yr4p
Created build tracker: /tmp/pip-req-tracker-og42yr4p
Entered build tracker: /tmp/pip-req-tracker-og42yr4p
Created temporary directory: /tmp/pip-install-p5b3_acb
1 location(s) to search for versions of django:
* https://pypi.org/simple/django/
Fetching project page and analyzing links: https://pypi.org/simple/django/
Getting page https://pypi.org/simple/django/
Found index url https://pypi.org/simple
Looking up "https://pypi.org/simple/django/" in the cache
Request header has "max_age" as 0, cache bypassed
Starting new HTTPS connection (1): pypi.org:443
https://pypi.org:443 "GET /simple/django/ HTTP/1.1" 200 42407
Could not fetch URL https://pypi.org/simple/django/: connection error: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Read timed out. - skipping
Skipping link: not a file: https://pypi.org/simple/django/
Given no hashes to check 0 links for project 'django': discarding no candidates
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement Django<3.3,>=3.2.5 (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for Django<3.3,>=3.2.5
Exception information:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/py/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pip/_vendor/resolvelib/resolvers.py", line 341, in resolve
    name, crit = self._merge_into_criterion(r, parent=None)
  File "/py/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pip/_vendor/resolvelib/resolvers.py", line 173, in _merge_into_criterion
    raise RequirementsConflicted(criterion)
pip._vendor.resolvelib.resolvers.RequirementsConflicted: Requirements conflict: SpecifierRequirement('Django<3.3,>=3.2.5')

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/py/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pip/_internal/resolution/resolvelib/resolver.py", line 127, in resolve
    result = self._result = resolver.resolve(
  File "/py/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pip/_vendor/resolvelib/resolvers.py", line 473, in resolve
    state = resolution.resolve(requirements, max_rounds=max_rounds)
  File "/py/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pip/_vendor/resolvelib/resolvers.py", line 343, in resolve
    raise ResolutionImpossible(e.criterion.information)
pip._vendor.resolvelib.resolvers.ResolutionImpossible: [RequirementInformation(requirement=SpecifierRequirement('Django<3.3,>=3.2.5'), parent=None)]

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/py/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/base_command.py", line 180, in _main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/py/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/req_command.py", line 205, in wrapper
    return func(self, options, args)
  File "/py/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pip/_internal/commands/install.py", line 318, in run
    requirement_set = resolver.resolve(
  File "/py/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pip/_internal/resolution/resolvelib/resolver.py", line 136, in resolve
    raise error from e
pip._internal.exceptions.DistributionNotFound: No matching distribution found for Django<3.3,>=3.2.5
Removed build tracker: '/tmp/pip-req-tracker-og42yr4p'
ERROR: Service 'app' failed to build : The command '/bin/sh -c python -m venv /py &&     /py/bin/pip install --upgrade pip &&     apk add --update --no-cache --virtual .build-deps     build-base     gcc     linux-headers &&     /py/bin/pip -vv install -r /requirements.txt &&     apk del .build-deps &&     adduser --disabled-password --no-create-home rsecuser &&     mkdir -p /vol/web/static &&     chown -R rsecuser:rsecuser /vol &&     chmod -R 755 /vol &&     chmod -R +x /scripts' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

Comment: What do you see if you add verbosity (`-v`) to the pip command?

Comment: Try to add `-v` or even `-vv` to your `pip` call to get more debugging details.

Comment: Thanks both. I made the change and update the post with the results

Comment: I saw the HTTPS timeout and restarted my OS, that seems to have resolved the issue and the build was successful. Not sure exactly what the issue really was. Thanks both for your help anyway! Verbosity for the win

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the reason is in virtual environment and the way how you want to hack it with `scripts` folder.

You don't necessary need to create virtual env inside docker as it is already isolated inside container.
Try to do same but without virtualenv in `Dockerfile`

```
FROM python:3.9-alpine3.14
LABEL maintainer="superapp"

ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

COPY requirements.txt /requirements.txt
COPY app /app
WORKDIR /app

RUN pip install --upgrade pip && \
    apk add --update --no-cache --virtual .build-deps \
    build-base \
    gcc \
    linux-headers && \
    pip install -r /requirements.txt && \
    apk del .build-deps && \
    adduser --disabled-password --no-create-home rsecuser && \
    mkdir -p /vol/web/static && \
    chown -R rsecuser:rsecuser /vol && \
    chmod -R 755 /vol

USER rsecuser
EXPOSE 8000

CMD ["run.sh"]
```

Answer (score 0):

I've done some modification if ur code and it worked for me.
Try to execute :
docker build .

```
FROM python:3.9-alpine3.14
LABEL maintainer="superapp"

ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

RUN mkdir /app

WORKDIR /app
COPY ./app /app

COPY ./scripts /scripts
COPY requirements.txt /requirements.txt
RUN pip install --upgrade pip && \
    apk add --update --no-cache --virtual .build-deps \
    build-base \
    gcc \
    linux-headers && \
    pip install -r /requirements.txt && \
    apk del .build-deps && \
    adduser --disabled-password --no-create-home rsecuser && \
    mkdir -p /vol/web/static && \
    chown -R rsecuser:rsecuser /vol && \
    chmod -R 755 /vol && \
    chmod -R +x /scripts

USER rsecuser
EXPOSE 8000

CMD ["run.sh"]
```